# How Do I Setup SSL with node.js and express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, express

I am trying to configure my application to run in HTTPS mode. I think my configuration is right, but the page is not loading, at all.

In my SSL folder, I have:

```
credentials.js
my-ca.pem
my-cert.pem
my.pem
```

Inside credentials, I have:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var credentials = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/my.pem', 'utf8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/my-cert.pem', 'utf8'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync(__dirname +  '/my-ca.pem', 'utf8'),
    passphrase: 'myphrase'
};

module.exports = credentials;
```

Then, in my `bin/www` file, I have:

```
var app = require('../app');
var https = require('https');
var credentials = require('../ssl/credentials');

https.createServer(credentials, app).listen(app.get('port'), app.get('ip'), function() {
  console.log('Running on port ' + app.get('port') + ' in ' + app.get('env') + ' mode.');
});
```

This should do the trick, no?

Answer (score 0):

Did you specifically go to **https://localhost:3000** respectively?

Comment: the port for the https is 443 @sctskw

Comment: Which is why I said respectively. You're free to choose whichever port you'd like. Just because it's https, doesn't mean it's automatically 443. It's whatever app.get('port') is set to, but I couldn't see that code

Comment: i set to 443, is working now, but i think i mess up, an error is showing: The identity of this website has not been verified.
 • Server's certificate does not match the URL.

Comment: This is expected, your'e using self-signed certifications which is why the browser warn you about. You can mark those certification as trust in your certification system manager.